# How can I read a file in python?

Tags: python, file, byte

Given some file that contain some text. How can I read Y bytes from this file after X bytes and print them?
I thought to use these functions:  `file = open("my_file", 'rb')` and `file.read(..)` but I don't sure how to do it with these functions.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it, you are just missing `seek` to select the position to read from:

```
file = open("my_file", 'rb')
file.seek(X)
content = file.read(Y)
file.close()
print(content)
```

However, if an error happened, your `file` would be left open for longer than necessary, so almost always you should use the `with` syntax instead, which will automatically dispose of `file` at the end of the block:

```
with open("my_file", 'rb') as file:
    file.seek(X)
    content = file.read(Y)
print(content)
```

Note that `content` will be bytes, not text.